# Dispatch Semaphore for UI

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, dispatchsemaphore

I wanted to animate the alpha of uiviews and i cannot seem to make it. It behaves weirdly and says error that running UI changes arent recommended to be run on background thread, but I dont know how do I make it run on the main one. Can somebody help me? I believe it skips the first UIView.animate block and performs whats in the second without any animation whatsoever.

func animateSemaphore() {

```
circleRed.alpha = 0.2
circleOrange.alpha = 0.2
circleGreen.alpha = 1

let dispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)

dispatchQueue.async {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 5, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.circleOrange.alpha = 1
        self.circleGreen.alpha = 0.2
    } completion: { (_) in
        print("1")
        dispatchSemaphore.signal()
    }
    
    dispatchSemaphore.wait()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 3, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.circleOrange.alpha = 0.2
        self.circleRed.alpha = 1
    } completion: { (_) in
        dispatchSemaphore.signal()
    }
    
    dispatchSemaphore.wait()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 5, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.circleOrange.alpha = 1
    } completion: { (_) in
        dispatchSemaphore.signal()
    }
    
    dispatchSemaphore.wait()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.circleOrange.alpha = 0.2
        self.circleRed.alpha = 0.2
        self.circleGreen.alpha = 1
    } completion: { (_) in
        self.animateSemaphore()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert any ui/animate related code inside main thread not inside a background queue

```
func animateSemaphore() {
    circleRed.alpha = 0.2
    circleOrange.alpha = 0.2
    circleGreen.alpha = 1
        
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 5, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.circleOrange.alpha = 1
        self.circleGreen.alpha = 0.2
    } completion: { (_) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 3, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
            self.circleOrange.alpha = 0.2
            self.circleRed.alpha = 1
        } completion: { (_) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 5, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
                self.circleOrange.alpha = 1
            } completion: { (_) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
                    self.circleOrange.alpha = 0.2
                    self.circleRed.alpha = 0.2
                    self.circleGreen.alpha = 1
                } completion: { (_) in 
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

OR play with `delay` instead of nesting animations

```
func animateSemaphore() {

    circleRed.alpha = 0.2
    circleOrange.alpha = 0.2
    circleGreen.alpha = 1

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 5, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.circleOrange.alpha = 1
        self.circleGreen.alpha = 0.2
    } completion: { (_) in
        print("1")
      
    }
    
   
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 8.5, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.circleOrange.alpha = 0.2
        self.circleRed.alpha = 1
    } completion: { (_) in
        
    }
    
   
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 14, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.circleOrange.alpha = 1
    } completion: { (_) in
       
    }
    
  
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 15.5, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        self.circleOrange.alpha = 0.2
        self.circleRed.alpha = 0.2
        self.circleGreen.alpha = 1
    } completion: { (_) in
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I get your point but I wanted to make it somehow be properly written. Isn't there any other way not to write everything into completion block of other  parts of code? When it's written this way, it's just overwhelming and not so easy to read.

Comment: From the previous animation. One completes, second one starts 5 second timer and then plays.

Comment: I tried this, but it skips for line 43 to line 59 and then 50.

Comment: I get it, but can I somehow avoid pasting everything into completion handlers, or there is no way around?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a config for creating animations (draft can be found here)
https://gist.github.com/maximkrouk/76163b3f2775dafc73c5633d155368cb
And add some flattening

```swift
public struct UIViewAnimation {
    private init(
        provider: UIViewAnimatiorProvider?,
        animations: @escaping () -> Void,
        completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil
    ) {
        self.provider = provider
        self.animations = animations
        self.completion = completion
    }
    
    public init(
        config: UIViewAnimatiorProvider,
        animations: @escaping () -> Void,
        completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil
    ) {
        self.init(
            provider: config,
            animations: animations,
            completion: completion
        )
    }
    
    let provider: UIViewAnimatiorProvider?
    let animations: () -> Void
    let completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?
    
    public func run() {
        if let provider = provider {
            provider.makeAnimator(
                for: animations,
                completion: completion ?? { _ in }
            ).animate()
        } else {
            animations()
            completion?(true)
        }
    }
    
    public func appendingCompletion(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) -> UIViewAnimation {
        UIViewAnimation(
            provider: provider,
            animations: animations,
            completion: { isFinished in
                self.completion?(isFinished)
                completion(isFinished)
            }
        )
    }
    
    public static let empty: UIViewAnimation = .init(
        provider: nil,
        animations: {},
        completion: nil
    )
}

extension UIViewAnimation {
    public static func sequence(_ animations: UIViewAnimation...) -> UIViewAnimation {
        guard var animation = animations.last else { return .empty }
        animations.dropLast().reversed().forEach { prevAnimation in
            let animate = animation.run
            animation = prevAnimation.appendingCompletion { _ in animate() }
        }
        return animation
    }
}
```

And use it like

```swift
extension UIView {
    func animateSemaphore() {
        let initialBackground = backgroundColor
        UIViewAnimation.sequence(
            UIViewAnimation(config: .init(duration: 2)) {
                self.backgroundColor = .red
            },
            UIViewAnimation(config: .init(duration: 2)) {
                self.backgroundColor = .green
            },
            UIViewAnimation(config: .init(duration: 2)) {
                self.backgroundColor = .red
            },
            UIViewAnimation(config: .init(duration: 2)) {
                self.backgroundColor = .green
            },
            UIViewAnimation(config: .init(duration: 2)) {
                self.backgroundColor = initialBackground
            }
        ).run()
    }
}

UIView().animateSemaphore()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use DispatchSemafore, but with the value 1.

```
        if presentedViewController != nil {
            let semafore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
            dismiss(animated: true) {
                semafore.signal()
            }
            semafore.wait()
        }
```